Granting GitLab `CI_JOB_TOKEN` permissions to container registry in another project
I want to use a job token to authenticate and access a different project’s container registry as described in the docs.
After granting my other project access, the pipeline is still unauthenticated to the container registry.
Error: POST https://gitlab-url/v2/project-registry/blobs/uploads/: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required;

Creating a project token with write_registry privileges is a workaround. Is there any way to achieve this without creating a project or group token?

And also in docs do not mention CI Job Token as allowed auth method for container registry: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/authenticate_with_container_registry.html
However from CI/CD it is. Maybe they mean CI/CD local to project, but not cross-project?
Also confused. Did you solve this?

@mspolitaev, no we use group_tokens instead
